# Selenium multi module integration with spring project monolithic module

Tags: spring, selenium, maven, testing, automated-tests

Project is Java and Maven.
I am required to integrate the selenium test which is under different project following multi module approach to integrate with single module spring project under one folder. Suggested information was to add the selenium test in src/test folder, but given this multi module looks difficult to follow that approach. Any best practices to follow ?

Comment: Why do you think it's difficult what are the issues ?

Comment: adding multi module in inside src/test does not look possible

Answer (score 0):

In pom there are scope field where you can mention test , this will make sure the dependencies are installed only for mvm test

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

> test
>
> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal
> use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation
> and execution phases. This scope is not transitive. Typically this
> scope is used for test libraries such as JUnit and Mockito. It is also
> used for non-test libraries such as Apache Commons IO if those
> libraries are used in unit tests (src/test/java) but not in the model
> code (src/main/java).

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes

> 3.4. Test
>
> This scope is used to indicate that dependency isn't required at
> standard runtime of the application, but is used only for test
> purposes. Test dependencies aren't transitive and are only present for
> test and execution classpaths.
>
> The standard use case for this scope is adding test library like JUnit
> to our application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```